# error CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, dynamic, lambda

I've converted some code from vb.net to c# but it's having problems with a lambda.

error CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

Here's the translated code..

```
dynamic ds = (JArray)o["Tables"][0]["Rows"];
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
    {connection.Open();
     ds.Select(ja =>
        connection.Execute("INSERT INTO dbo.AddPlay(UserId, Timestamp, YoutubeId, Source, PlayCount, Rating) " + 
                " VALUES(ja(0).Value<string>(), ja(1).Value<string>() ja(2).Value<string>(), ja(3).Value<string>(), GetInt(ja(4)), GetInt(ja(5)))"));
    }
```

Comment: Your code has a problem - did you really mean to insert the string "ja(0).Value<string>()" into your database? Also, you should be using parameters and not string substitution. Finally, `Select()` isn't for replacing a `foreach` loop.

Comment: oh no. Well spotted ! I have the double disadvantage of being a VB.net programmer trying to convert my VB code to C# in an Azure Function App that has no Intellisense.  Why is using Select() wrong to use to loop my JArray ?

Comment: The signature of `Select` is `public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
 this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
 Func<TSource, TResult> selector
)`. If you aren't using/needing the result `IEnumerable<TResult>` then it is probably the wrong operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `foreach` and creating a parameterized `SqlCommand` is best practice

```
var ds = (JArray)o["Tables"][0]["Rows"];

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(cnnString)) {
    connection.Open();
    var cmdIns = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.AddPlay(UserId, Timestamp, YoutubeId, Source, PlayCount, Rating) VALUES(@UserId, @Timestamp, @YoutubeId, @Source, @PlayCount, @Rating)", connection);
    cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@Timestamp", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@YoutubeId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@Source", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@PlayCount", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@Rating", SqlDbType.Int);

    foreach (var ja in ds) {
        cmdIns.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = ja[0].Value<string>();
        cmdIns.Parameters["@Timestamp"].Value = ja[1].Value<string>();
        cmdIns.Parameters["@YoutubeId"].Value = ja[2].Value<string>();
        cmdIns.Parameters["@Source"].Value = ja[3].Value<string>();
        cmdIns.Parameters["@PlayCount"].Value = GetInt(ja[4]);
        cmdIns.Parameters["@Rating"].Value = GetInt(ja[5]);

        cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked with a little tweek.  The cmdIns.Parameters["@UserId"] = ja(0).Value<string>();  should read cmdIns.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = ja[0].Value<string>();

Comment: Interesting. I guess I didn't have enough data types to get a type error.

Answer (score 4):

`dynamic` causes the variable type to be determined at runtime rather than compile time, which doesn't play well with lambda expressions.  But you don't need a dynamic variable here; you already know the type is `JArray` because you are doing a cast.  So change the variable declaration from `dynamic` to `JArray` and that will fix the compiler error:

```
JArray ds = (JArray)o["Tables"][0]["Rows"];
```

Your code has other problems however:

- `SqlConnection` does not contain an `Execute` method.  You need to create a `SqlCommand` and use its `ExecuteNonQuery` method to do the insert.
- Your SQL will not work as intended because you are not actually placing the values of the `JArray` into the command string. You should be using SQL parameters anyhow.

See [@NetMage's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286669/10263) to see how to fix these issues.